# How can I get my website to redirect .html pages to the index.php using advanced mod_rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, browser-history, modx

if you look at

```
http://ecocool.zadesigns.com
```

click on `help` link and it goes to

```
http://ecocool.zadesigns.com/help
```

this works, but if you physically type "http://ecocool.zadesigns.com/help.html"

it does not work.

how can i modify the htaccess file so that if i type

```
http://ecocool.zadesigns.com/help.html
```

into the address bar it removes the `.html` from the URL, loads the index.php file and then sends me to the correct page.

Here is the htaccess file.

```
 <ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
     Options +FollowSymLinks
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
 </ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First rule redirects from the `html` to directory style, we don't use any condition because we don't want to check if the file exists or not.

Second rule will redirect the directory like format to the index.php unless it is index.php which it then does nothing.

So basically if you click on the link:

```
http://ecocool.zadesigns.com/anything.html
```

It will make the link look like this to the user:

```
http://ecocool.zadesigns.com/anything/
```

And will then internally show the `index.php?q=anything` result.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you don't mind having the URL display the `.html` and just want to serve the `index.php` on its place then use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So basically if you click on the link:

```
http://ecocool.zadesigns.com/anything.html
```

It will internally show the `index.php?q=anything` result and the URL will remain:

```
http://ecocool.zadesigns.com/anything.html
```

Comment: this was the best answer so thank you both for helping.  even thought your answer was correct I actually have other issues with conflicting systems both fighting for control of index.php and routing.  ill have to ask another question about that

Comment: @ZurielAndrusyshyn sure, when you do that drop me a comment with the link and I will take a look.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MODX Revolution, go to System > Content Types and remove the .html extension for HTML content types.

Clear your site cache, and any links built using Wayfinder or MODX link tags (`[[~ ]]`) will no longer include the .html extension.

You'll be able to access that page using http://ecocool.zadesigns.com/wtf

Comment: I actually have it working now where I had to remove .html  so I don't exactly know if its a combo of your answer as well but it was helpful so thank you!

Comment: @ZurielAndrusyshyn - This is the right answer. mod_rewrite is not supposed to be used like Prix's post in this case. Modx has a built-in system that is both much faster and much prettier.